# How to safely comment PHP inside JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, intellij-idea

How can I comment the following code?

```js
function test() {
    object.test("<?php echo get_test(); ?>", "anotherTest_<?php echo $testID; ?>", "<?php echo $stillTest; ?>", "10", "20", "<?php echo get_sample(); ?>", variables, params, attributes);
}
```

I tried with

```js
/*
function test() {
    object.test("<?php echo get_test(); ?>", "anotherTest_<?php echo $testID; ?>", "<?php echo $stillTest; ?>", "10", "20", "<?php echo get_sample(); ?>", variables, params, attributes);
}
*/
```

but in IntelliJ IDEA the PHP code is still colored, so I am not sure if it works as intended.

Comment: Remember that PHP runs before the page is sent to the browser, javascript after. In this case, the PHP will still run so everything gets echoed, but the javascript will all still be commented out.

Comment: One option is to just put a `return` at the beginning of the function

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of how does it look on your end? Checking this here on latest IDEA version and the unwanted coloring doesn't appear: https://i.gyazo.com/e5a8719e4ba7a43bc833720bbe580ba8.png

Comment: @Dmitrii You need to save it as a PHP file (with the official [PHP plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6610-php) installed).

Comment: These comments are outside of `<?php ... ?>`, so in that context, they are not PHP comments, but JavaScript comments.

Comment: @ᴜsᴇʀ please attach a full file screenshot as seen on your end. That would eliminate all our second guesses.